# Integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-[a\cos(2\psi)+b\cos(\psi)]}d\psi$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-[a\cos(\phi+\psi)+b\cos(\phi-\psi)]}d\psi$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm trying to determine the following integrals:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-[a\cos(2\psi)+b\cos(\psi)]}d\psi$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-[a\cos(\phi+\psi)+b\cos(\phi-\psi)]}d\psi.$$
Similar integrals can be solved by means of the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order zero.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first integral can be expressed as a series of products of modified Bessel functions. The [Jacobi-Anger expansion for the modified Bessel functions of the first kind](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.35.E2) reads
\begin{equation}
e^{z\cos\theta}=I_{0}\left(z\right)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I_{k}\left(z\right)%
\cos\left(k\theta\right)
\end{equation}
then
\begin{align}
e^{-[a\cos(2\psi)+b\cos(\psi)]}&=\left( I_{0}\left(-a\right)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I_{k}\left(-a\right)\cos\left(2k\psi\right) \right)\left( I_{0}\left(-b\right)+2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}I_{m}\left(-b\right)\cos\left(m\psi\right) \right)\\
&= I_{0}\left(a\right) I_{0}\left(b\right)+2 I_{0}\left(a\right)\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^mI_{m}\left(b\right)\cos\left(m\psi\right)\\
&\hspace{2cm}+2 I_{0}\left(b\right)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^kI_{k}\left(a\right)\cos\left(2k\psi\right)\\
&\hspace{2cm}+4\sum_{k,m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+m}I_{k}\left(a\right)I_{m}\left(b\right)\cos\left(2k\psi\right)\cos\left(m\psi\right)
\end{align}
After integration over $(0,2\pi)$, the second and third series vanish while, in the double sum, only the terms with $m=2k$ survive with
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^{2\pi}\cos^22k\psi\,d\psi=\pi
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{align}
 F_1&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-[a\cos(2\psi)+b\cos(\psi)]}\,d\psi\\
 &=2\pi I_{0}\left(a\right) I_{0}\left(b\right)+4\pi\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^kI_{k}\left(a\right)I_{2k}\left(b\right)
\end{align}
This result and many similar ones are obtained in the frame of the generalization of Bessel functions to several variables (see [Gupta](https://fdocuments.in/document/on-addition-theorems-of-the-generalised-bessel-coefficients.html) or the many papers by [Dattoli](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226736031_Theory_of_generalized_Bessel_functions), for example).

The second integral can be put into a closed form, by remarking that one can transform
\begin{align}
 a\cos(\phi+\psi)+b\cos(\phi-\psi)&=(a+b)\cos\phi\cos\psi-(a-b)\sin\phi\sin\psi\\
 &=\Delta\left(\frac{(a+b)\cos\phi}{\Delta} \cos\psi- \frac{(a-b)\sin\phi}{\Delta}\sin\psi\right)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 \Delta&=\sqrt{(a+b)^2\cos^2\phi+(a-b)^2\sin^2\phi }\\
 &=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos2\phi}
\end{align}
Then defining an angle $0\le\theta<\pi$ by $\tan\theta=\frac{a-b}{a+b}\tan\phi$, the integral reads
\begin{align}
F_2&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-[a\cos(\phi+\psi)+b\cos(\phi-\psi)]}\,d\psi\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-\Delta(\cos\theta\cos\phi-\sin\theta\cos\phi)}\,d\psi\\
 &=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-\Delta\cos(\psi+\theta)}\,d\psi\\
 &=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-\Delta\cos\psi}\,d\psi\\
 =&2\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-\Delta\cos\psi}\,d\psi
\end{align}
where the integration variable was shifted, as the domain of integration covers a period of the function and where we used the symmetry of the integrand. From the [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E1) for the modified Bessel function of the first kind and of order $0$:
\begin{align}
 I_{0}\left(\Delta\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{\pm \Delta\cos\psi}
\theta\,d\psi
\end{align}
we deduce
\begin{equation}
F_2=2\pi I_0\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos2\phi} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: When your discussion involves Bessel functions $I_k$, it is probably not wise to name your integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$ :)

Comment: You're wright! Corrected now, thanks.